WordPress Redierction
I would appreciate it if you could help me to sort out the below issue. I have created a blog using Custom Post-Type in WP. now all my blog links are showing as follows. how can I remove redirection on it?
https://halaarabia.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fhalaarabia.com%2Fblogs%2Fwhat-is-dmc-destination-management-company%2F

That's a link to the login page, because your site thinks you need to log in to see that content. Have you restricted visibility to logged-in users?

And where are you seeing that? I'd expect WordPress to still generate links to the article directly, but to redirect you to the login page if you click it and you're logged out. I wouldn't expect it to generate links with the login step automatically.

Hi. I found those links when I scanned the site with Screaming Frog for SEO analysis. also, I have blocked indexing my wp-login page. Because of this my blog posts are not indexing
